# HTML passes parameters to Java servlet incorrectly

Tags: java, html, servlets, unicode, encoding

I have a regular HTML form, that passes parameters to a Java servlet with POST method. It contains unicode characters.
When I print the parameters in Java that I got from the HTML, my string dies hard. No problem unless it is pure ASCII, but unicode strings disintegrate.

HTML

[image]

Servlet

[image]

So for example, when I pass *asd* it is show correctly, but *niké* becomes to *nikĂŠ*

Please if you know a solution, let me know!

Comment: Hi, this seems to be an encoding problem. I guess the client uses windows-1250 and the server uses utf-8.

Comment: "It is shown correctly", where? in the debugger? in another page?

Comment: Don't link to pictures / screenshots of code, include the code in your question itself (as text, not as an image).

Comment: As mentioned it's an encoding problem. When posting questions, don't use screenshots for code, they are unreliable in the long term. Paste your code using SO's editor.

Comment: I am not sure if my Java IDE uses utf-8. i tried to `System.out.println("áéőű");` but my result on Console was **áé??**
As I am very new in Java I couldn't find any way to fix this encoding problem.
But when I add utf-8 HTML string like _<h1>áéőű</h1>_ from servlet, that shows correctly.
I am totally lost with it.

Comment: Okay, next time I don't use images :)

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use ENCODE HTML before send the request and DECODE HTML when you recive